# Android back Stack on Activity

Tags: android

I'm a new Android developer, I have a simple question :

for moving from one activity to another I use :

```
 Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
 this.startActivity(i);
```

and to go back from the first activity to the second Activity I use :

```
 this.finish();
 overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

I just finish the activity, my problem is that I'm launching the activity and closing it everytime. I want to prevent this, and just keep the Second Activity in the background.

Can you clarify on how to do this ? I'm just using this, but it doesn't make sense for me

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

But how to prevent closing the second activity ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can keep Android activity in the background. You Can save your activity state and recreate it accordingly to Activity Life Cycle.

overridePendingTransition function is only for the animation purposes.

doc:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int, int)

You should check the Android Activity LifeCycle thought, if you don't understand it completely.

**Activity**: "An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do"

**Background Activity**: "an activity that is not visible to the user and has been paused"

Comment: But how to pause an activity instead of finishing it, and going back to it instead of creating a new instance of it each time

Comment: That's android activity life cycle architecture. If I understood you correctly, what you want is a cached view - and that's something that android activities cannot offer you, since the state of the activity is managed by the os, which decision is beyond your scope.